# How to enforce code execution order in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

## Observed behavior

In a Jupyter Notebook that has been presented, the notebook yields the following output:

```
ERP at 175 ms of trial 1
Average ERP at 175 ms of all trials
```

Followed by 2 pictures:

```
<display image 0>
<display image 1>
```

When the following code is executed:

```
z = sX_train[1,1,:,int(0.175*40)]
c="channels.txt"
print("ERP at 175 ms of trial 1")
topoplot(z,c)

# also compute the average ERP of all trials in first epoch at 180 ms
z = np.zeros(64)
for channel in range(0,z.shape[0]):
    z[channel] = np.mean(sX_train[:,1,channel,int(0.175*40)])
print("Average ERP at 175 ms of all trials")
topoplot(z,c)
```

## Expected behavior

However, I would expect the output to be:

```
ERP at 175 ms of trial 1
<display image 0>
Average ERP at 175 ms of all trials
<display image 1>
```

if the code were to be executed from top to bottom.

## Analysis

I think this is some a-synchronous function, as it takes longer to compute the `topoplot` function than to compute the print statements. However I can't find anything on threading or syncing. A quick and dirty solution would be to modify the topoplot to return something so that the code must wait on it before it prints the description.

## Question

How can I ensure the output is displayed in the order it is written within a cell in a Jupyter Notebook, without modifying the code to build dependencies on eachother?

Comment: Unless specifically printed, the last element of a cell is displayed. So if you have every element in a separate cell, it should work. Could you provide a more detailed example of the notebook?

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I did not think of the option to separate the commands in separate cells, that indeed enforces the outputs to be in the correct order. At the same time, for readability it is not desirable to create so many separate cells for a few plots. So I took the liberty of modifying my question to "within a single cell". I will try to work on how I can share a MWE `.ipynb`,  since I currently don't have permission to share the `topoplot` function.